MS Access Expression Builder Value from another Table
I have two tables - tblMain and tblConstants. I want a column in tblMain that references a value in tblConstants, but expression builder doesn't allow it.
Example Data:
tblMain
 ID*  | dblLength | tblOverall
------------------------------
 1    | 100       | {expression}

tblConstants:
 Name*      | Val
--------------------
 dblSample  | 100

Sample expression:
[dblLength] + [tblConstants].[dblSample]
But this results in the following error:

All my searching has found that I could create relationships between the tables, but this requires me to duplicate the constants as columns in tblMain.
Is there a neater way to do this?

Did you try domain aggregation function DLOOKUP() or DSUM() instead of [tblConstants].[dblSample]?

"The expression DLookUp("[Name]","tblConstants", "[Name]=dblSample") cannot be used in a calculated column."

Then use a query. Apart from very special cases, avoid calculated fields.

Or use a regular field and fill it with data-macro.

I tried using a data-macro, based on an 'table after update' event, but it seems that there's no way to know which record triggered the update, so I would need to calculate all values in a column for every update. Currently investigating the query option.

The query seems to be working. I didn't realise you could do a select statement as part of a maths operation. @Gustav - If you respond with an answer, I can accept it as the solution. Thanks.

Then use a query. Apart from very special cases, avoid calculated fields.
In a select query, you can perform all sorts of calculations using fields from a single table or a set of joined tables.
